# Pass returnUrl from ActionLink from view to Login Form that redirects back to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, formsauthentication, returnurl

I have read many SO posts about **returnUrl** as it pertains to forms authentication by default of `[authorize] MyController`, but I haven't read anything on simply passing the returnUrl where the only authentication takes place after the [HttpPost] with a login or register form  and anonymous users.
In this case, I want the redirect to come from the original link and passed to the action where the users are authenticated via form authentication. This redirect should take the user back to the page being viewed after they 1) click register or login ActionLinks and then 2) submit the form successfully. This is on a dev server so HTTPS is not a requirement ATM.

**Here is the elements without the necessary syntax/code for passing returnUrl**

**_LoginPartial:**

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null}, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li> //returnUrl???
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li> // returnUrl???
```

**Login View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){...} //new { returnUrl } ???
```

**Login Get ActionResult:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{   
    //There is other ways to store the route
    TempData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

**Login Post ActionResult:**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password,     persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(TempData["ReturnUrl"].ToString());
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

---

**Solution**
Thanks to [SlightlyMoist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3444276/slightlymoist) I was able to resolve the issue. While the code is small in size the ability and know-how of `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["key"]` seems to be invaluable IMO. So the only modification done as per SM was done inside the ActionLinks of the **_LoginPartial** view:

```
<li>
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: new {@returnUrl = Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"])}, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
</li>

<li>
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: new {@returnUrl = Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"])}, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
</li>
```

**ALSO** 
As per SM yet again, the `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` works as well:

```
<li>
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: new {@returnUrl = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery},htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })
</li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply parse the current route / URL as a routeValue in your login action link.

Something like this should do the trick

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", 
    new {@returnUrl = Url.Action(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())})
```

Comment: And if there is an arg in the absolute url such as _http://yardpenalty.com/sporting-goods/1234_ the arg gets placed last in the Url.Action? Also do you know a good place where I can get more familiar with how 'ViewData.RouteData' works? Thanks a million.

Comment: Correct. Or alternatively, use @returnUrl = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery. As for RouteData, it's basically just a collection of all parameters extracted from your route, including "controller" and "action". Here's a pretty good article about it all http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx

Comment: Once I get it up and working I will show results in my question and give you credit for answer. Thanks again and again.

Comment: I think below is easier and more useful:





`@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { returnUrl = Request.RawUrl })"> Log in </a>`

The controller:

    public ActionResult ActionName(string returnUrl){
  return string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)
                     ? RedirectToAction("Index", "ControllerName")
                     : (ActionResult)Redirect(returnUrl);

Answer (score 5):

Similar idea, but I simply added ViewBag.ReturnUrl in the view, and modified the Register and Login methods.  This is because not all Login and Register locations will want to return to the page, and this way you have control on a view by view basis.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "/Home/Live";
}
```

And in the _LoginPartial:

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Log in", "Login", new { area = "", controller = "Account", ReturnUrl=ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new { id = "loginLink" } )
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. It worked for me in MVC 5.